# Is theire any specific caution to take before resize btrfs

Tags: partition, btrfs, defragmentation

#### Current situation

I have an almost full `/home` partition, with just 4.4Go remaining space, when my `/` is more than half empty.

Both of the two partitions are in Btrfs, as you can see:

```
% lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,FSAVAIL,FSUSE%,MOUNTPOINT,SIZE -e7
NAME   FSTYPE FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT              SIZE
sda                                                238,5G
├─sda1 vfat      4,6G     0% /boot/efi               4,7G
├─sda2 swap                  [SWAP]                  4,8G
├─sda3 btrfs    67,0G    37% / 107,1G              107,1G
└─sda4 btrfs     4,4G    96% /home                   122G
```

#### What I want to do

Then naturaly I want to downsise the `/` partition to make more space to `/home`.

#### The question

Before downsizing `/` and upsizing `/home` I am naturally afraid. I know their is no defragmentation tool for Btrfs because the specific mechanism of Btrfs have no need, but I still a little bit incredulous.

At least, is their a defragmentation analizis tool for Btrfs or something allowing me to know how safe the resizing will be? Is their any caution I can take before?

Naturally I made a backup before. But if I can avoid to restore them it would be great.

Comment: Why do you think defragmentation has anything to do with the resize? How do you plan to resize?

Comment: @pipe I whant to resize sda3 to 50% size and give the remaining space to sda4.